# Class in python which returns ambiguous values of series

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to write a class for fitting parameters of a certain function.
I pass an object called dft3data which is a DataFrame.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
from scipy.integrate import quad

class Fit_My_Function(object):
        def __init__(self, dft3data):
                self.dft3data = dft3data

        def integrand(self,t, alpha, r):
                self.t = t
                self.alpha = alpha
                self.r = r
                return np.exp(-self.alpha*(self.t-self.r))**2

        def my_function(self,parameters, rho):
                self.alpha = parameters[0]
                self.r = parameters[1]
                self.rho = rho
                return quad(self.integrand, 0, self.rho, args=(self.alpha, self.r))[0]

        def fit(self):
                self.alpha_0 = 1
                self.r_0 = 1
                self.rho_0 = self.dft3data['rab']/self.dft3data['R_zero']
                self.vec_expint = np.vectorize(self.my_function)
                self.res = opt.minimize(self.my_function, np.asarray([self.alpha_0, self.r_0]), self.rho_0, method='CG', tol=1.e-2, options={'gtol': 0.01, 'maxiter': 5})
                return self.res.x
```

The error message is throwing when I call the fit method:

```
File "/home/test.py", line 27, in fit
    self.res = opt.minimize(self.my_function, np.asarray([self.alpha_0, self.r_0]), self.rho_0, method='CG', tol=1.e-2, options={'gtol': 0.01, 'maxiter': 5})
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 442, in minimize
    return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1228, in _minimize_cg
    gfk = myfprime(x0)
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 292, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 688, in approx_fprime
    return _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args=args)
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 622, in _approx_fprime_helper
    f0 = f(*((xk,) + args))
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 292, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/home/test.py", line 20, in my_function
    return quad(self.integrand, 0, self.rho, args=(self.alpha, self.r))[0]
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 315, in quad
    points)
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 364, in _quad
    if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
  File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 887, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

As I understand it correctly the issue appears while using the scipy minimize method. Could anybody spell out what is wrong in this code, please?

Comment: The message reworded is that you have passed a (Pandas) Series where a (boolean) truth value is expected. It's offering advice. You can qualify the Series with any of those alternatives, such as bool(). (But you should probably examine your code to see what you really meant to pass.)

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful, I solved the problem.

Comment: Good! You're most welcome.